# Do I have to update to 8.3.0 first before I can update to latest stable release?

Tags: 8, updating, composer

I pritty messed up my site by updating my 8.2.6 site as followed.

Step 1: I edit my composer.json file. I replaced the replace to require
`"replace": {
        "drupal/core": "~8.3"` to

`"require": {
        "drupal/core": "~8.3"`

Because I wanted to update core and vendor I did this composer command
step 2: `composer update --with-dependencies`

step 3: Site was broken unexpected error (500) using WAMP 2.4.23, php version 7.0.10 and mysql 5.7.14.

Do I have to update to 8.3.0 first before I can update to latest stable release?
- example: `composer require drupal/core:8.3.0`

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: unexpected error please try again later, when inspect with google console only get 500 error. Nothing specific

Comment: Need the actual error.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (500 Service unavailable

Comment: That's your browser/server's generic error message. Check your logs for the actual php error message

Comment: You should enable [Drupal and PHP's error printing](https://blog.liip.ch/archive/2016/06/20/lets-debug-drupal-8.html). What you're seeing is a suppressed version of the error (no stack traces, no error codes).

Comment: Thnx, I restored a backup from 11-05-17 So the site is working now, but on drupal-8.2.6. I will walk trough the update procedure again. And will enable the PHP's error printing. If still problems occur I'll try the manual procedure as written [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2700999)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your modules. If you are using [DisplaySuite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) there is an issue with updating because of the change from `layout_plugin` to the `layout_discovery` module. See [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2867499). And have a look at the [8.3.0 Release Notes](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases/8.3.0) for broken changes and affected modules.

Comment: Interesting, I think this is the problem, after reading this issue I think I can do 2 things. add patch (new to me) or 1)Suggestion, update all modules that use layout_plugin, panels,panelizer, ds
2) Do not run cache clear, go to extend and uninstall layout_plugin
3) After start uninstall upper error with layout_discovery, not found service.(But layout_plugin is uninstalled with success )
4) drush en layout_discovery, update succes

Comment: But Ibefore start with the suggestion, I have to update 'drupal/core' first?

Comment: I updated the core first, then I've upgrated Display Suite to the new branch and at least I patched Display Suite.